# Remote Desktop and Ctrl + Alt + Del

Tags: windows-7, desktop, remote, remote-connection, ctrl-alt-delete

I'm just starting to use a remote desktop connection from my laptop for the first time to control a PC running a 8 screen video wall. When I remote into the PC, the screen on the remote PC stays at the Ctrl + Alt + Delete screen and I have a "pseudo login" running in the remote window. Is this how it's supposed to work? Can I not remove that screen when I log in and see my actions on the screen for real, instead of in the window on my laptop?

As it is now, I have no visibility of anything on the physical screens (apparently RDC allows visibility of only one screen) and the remote machine stays locked when I'm done.

Comment: Please post a picture to clarify what you are describing. You can configure MSTSC to use all the monitors on the connecting system, under `Options -> Display -> "Use all my monitors for the remote session"` if that is what you mean in the second paragraph. also in RDP connections, C+A+D is `Ctrl + Alt + End`

Answer (score 9):

Remote Desktop Connection always locks the screen of the computer you remote into. If you need the computers physical screen to show what you are doing, you would need to look at a third party software such as VNC or Teamviewer.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the reply. Can you unlock a PC using Teamviewer?

Comment: Yes, it will bring you to the login screen when remoting in if you are not already logged in on the computer.

Comment: @Confuzing - RDC locks always only on Windows Desktop Editions, while on Windows Server Editions you can have 2 connections or more if you enable Terminal Services Licensing service.

Comment: @Zina Hmm never used server edition. So it shows what is happening on the remote computer screen, and doesn't just show the logon screen?

Comment: No, A RDC is always private, meaning on a Server you and I would be able to connect and you would have your screen and I would have mine (even with the same user) and the console screen would be a third session. For screen sharing you could use Teamviewer or VNC (as suggested by yourself).